# Unity TCP socket connection not working on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, sockets, unityscript, mac-app-store, appstore-sandbox

I'm trying to publish my Unity multiplayer game to Mac App Store, but by some reason in production the socket fails to connect to server, throwing the following exception:
 "**Access denied System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind**".

I have "**com.apple.security.network.client**" and "**com.apple.security.app-sandbox**" entitlement, but it does not work. HTTP requests work OK though. 
If I test the app in debug build - it works..what could be blocking it ? The port I'm using is 16005

This is the client connection code:

```
var tcpClient = new TcpClient();
tcpClient.Connect(Host, Port);
networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
listenThread = new Thread(ListenToServer);
listenThread.Start();
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I Solved the problem.
It turns out I had to add the server entitlement too.
(Although I'm not starting any server nor listening for incoming connections).

So adding "**com.apple.security.network.server**" entitlement solved the problem